# what all testing will be done by apple testers on my iphone apps

Tags: iphone

I have a doubt, after finishing my Iphone apps, if i submit that for testing... How they test my application. what are the testing strategies they use, like blackbox testing, unit testing like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 main aspects as far as testing is concerned.

1 The application should absolutely not contain any hidden or private APIs.
2 There should be no crashes in the App.
3 Proper use of Controls.(i.e if you create an iPad app then it should have some controls which are specific to iPad).

Keep these points in mind and i'm sure your app wont be rejected.

None of my app have been rejected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the two main causes of apps to be rejected are Core Functionality and Crashes. So make sure it does what its says on the tin and it doesnt crash (through memory leaks, etc..)